# Diagnolization of a non-invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for the subspace formed by the columns of $A$. Can there exist a diagonal matrix $C$ such that:

$$Cx_{\mathcal{B}} = (Ax)_{\mathcal{B}}$$

if $\text{span}(A) $ doesn't equal $\mathbb{R^n}$ and

a) $\mathcal{B}$ consists only of the columns of $A$

b) $\mathcal{B}$ doesn't consist only of the columns of $A$

This isn't homework, just curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: What do the symbols $Cx_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $(Ax)_{\mathcal{B}}$ mean?

Comment: I guess $(\cdot)_{\mathcal{B}}$ means the coordinates of $\cdot$ w.r.t. the basis $\mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to diagonalize a non-zero , non-invertible matrix,  that is not already in a diagonal form with $0$'s on the diagonal ,since the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal entries $a_{ii}$, where the $a_
{ii}$ are eigenvalues, and $0$ is not considered to be an eigenvalue. The diagonal entries are the eigenvalues.

EDIT: I may be wrong, or this may be a technical issue. I thought eigenvalues were supposed to be non-zero, but after a search, it seems many sources do include the possibility of $0$ as an eigenvalue. IF $0$ is accepted as an eigenvalue, then a non-invertible matrix may be diagonalizable, as the example in the comments below shows.
EDIT2: Diagonalizability ultimately comes down to having enough linearly-independent eigenvectors to form a basis for the eigenspace; I think this is what is called the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Right, let me edit.

Comment: This is still false. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, which diagonalizes to $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Please see the edit I just did.

Comment: I never saw zeros being expelled from the party of acceptable candidates to join the ranks of eigenvalues.

Comment: Maybe my class notes where from some eccentric prof. It may be better to delete the answer.

Comment: But, at the end of the day, it comes down to having enough L.I eigenvectors to form a basis for the eigenspace, so you're most likely right that $0$ is/should be acceptable eigenvalue.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if there's a nonzero $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. This classical definition of eigenvalues implies that if a $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then its associated eigenspace is at least one-dimensional (span of that $x$). I'd bet there's a typo in your (or your prof's?) definition of the eigen-guys and which of them must be nonzero.

Comment: Pavel: I just got too much of a head-start on senility: I realized what I was really thinking is that the zero _vector_ is not consider an eigenvector, but instead, I stupidly confused it with the zero _eigenvalue_. I thought I had at least some $40$ years before becoming senile, but maybe not.

Comment: Anyone else here also believe I should delete my answer?